# Tabs + Slider Slick (3): при реализации табов с переключением 3-х слайдеров при breakpointe - slick не правильно работает

Tags: tabs, slick.js

я верстаю интернет магазин. и мне надо реализовать переключение трех табов- соответственно меняется три слайдера (два из которых скрыты `display:none;`)
При ресайзе на breakpoint слайдер не правильно перестраивается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



        <title></title>

        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="new_title">
            <h3 id="new_prod" data-id="1" class="slider_tab upper active">Новинки</h3>
            <h3 id="new_sale" data-id="2" class="slider_tab upper">Распродажа</h3>
            <h3 id="new_top" data-id="3" class="slider_tab upper new_title-top">топ продаж</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="tabs_content">
            <div class="slider slider_item slider_item_1 " data-slider="1">
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_1</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_1</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_1</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_1</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_1</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_1</h1>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider slider_item slider_item_2" data-slider="2" >
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_2</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_2</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_2</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_2</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_2</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_2</h1>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider slider_item slider_item_3" data-slider="3" >
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_3</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_3</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_3</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_3</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_3</h1>
    _2
                </div>
                <div class="product ">
                    <h1>slider_3</h1>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.custom-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/maskedinput.js"></script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

script:

```
function slider_tab() {
    $(".slider_tab").on("click", function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            return;
        }
        $('.slider_tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var item_attr = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.slider_item').css("display", "none");

        $('.slider_item').each(function () {
            var attr_slider = $(this).attr('data-slider');
            if(item_attr==attr_slider){
                $(this).css("display", "block");
                $(this).slick('reinit');

            }
        })
    })
}
```

На desktope — `$(this).slick('reinit');` — этот кусок кода спасает, но на других расширениях — нет
Инициализация:

```
<script>
 $('.slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='img/slider_arr_l.png'>",
        nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='img/slider_arr_r.png'>",
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1280,
                settings: {

                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {

                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]

    });
</script>
```

Comment: А где код инициализации slick?

Comment: добавила код инициализации